# Why is python collecting even if gc disabled?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

This code

```
import gc
gc.disable()
print gc.isenabled()
print len(gc.get_objects())
class Foo(): pass
print len(gc.get_objects())

a=[]
print len(gc.get_objects())
for i in xrange(10000):
    a.append(Foo())

print len(gc.get_objects())
a=[] # Should not collect
print len(gc.get_objects())
gc.collect()
print len(gc.get_objects())
```

Produces this output

```
False
3754
3755
3756
13756
3756
3374
```

I would expect the second to last number to be 13756, because the gc is disabled and when the original `a` list goes out of scope, it should not drop those objects. Apparently python is collecting those objects anyway. Why ?

python is 2.7.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because garbage collection only deals with circular references. Quoting from the [`gc` module documention](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html):

> Since the collector supplements the reference counting already used in Python, you can disable the collector if you are sure your program does not create reference cycles.

CPython uses reference counting to clean up *most* objects. When you replace the list `a` referred to with an empty list, the reference counts for the old list dropped to 0, so it is deleted *at that point*. Deleting the list causes the reference counts for the `Foo()` instances to drop to 0 too, etc.

If you create circular references instead, *and* disable garbage collection, you'll see the numbers remain constant:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.bar = Bar(self)

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
```

Comment: How can I get information of the unreachable objects and when they are collected?

Comment: [`gc.garbage`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.garbage) gives you a list of objects that could *not* be collected; there is no API to list anything that is unreachable and *can* be collected, because that would require an explicit collection run, which then breaks the cycles at that time. You can set the thresholds to influence when a cycle will be run, but you cannot query when one will run because it is not time-based.